# FDTD validation with Poynting Vector

Tags: finite-differences

I'm attempting to validate my FDTD optics simulator results.

Visually, I can see that my output is nearly identical to that produced by [Meep](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep), the only difference being a slight phase shift. Using a point source in the middle of a 1k+1 by 1k+1 domain, I can place the image produced by my code next to that produced by Meep, and they appear to be part of the same simulation (in the 2D case).

[image: Meep on the left, my code on the right]

(Ez field from a 2D TMz simulation, PML disabled)

However, for my thesis, I need a way to numerically validate my results, using Meep as a benchmark (though I would welcome suggestions for a better package).

(For simplicity's sake, I'm only considering the 2D, Hx/Hy/Ez case here, with the Ez output field pictured above.)

It's been suggested that I:

1. Calculate a Poynting vector field for both Meep's and my output
2. Compensate for scaling by finding max/min for each, and scaling the data so that they cover the same domain
3. Integrate (?) and calculate the difference

I am told that analyzing the Poynting vector field, rather than the raw Ez data, should eliminate the phase difference.

I've been through [Taflove's FDTD bible](http://books.google.com/books/about/Computational_Electrodynamics.html?id=viVRAAAAMAAJ), but haven't found anything that applies to this case (though I may be missing something).

I've been beating my head against the wall on this one for far longer than I care to admit. Any references, example code (C#, C, C++, CUDA, OpenCL, Python, Mathematica, Matlab, etc.) would be invaluable, or any easy-ish-to-follow (as far as emag can be) steps, or, for that matter, *any* advice.

**Edit**
If this isn't the correct place to ask this question, please point me towards the one that is. This topic falls **somewhere** on the inside of the math, physics and engineering triangle, though my specific area is electrical engineering.

Comment: Have you thought about comparing to a simple, analytical solution such as the Sommerfeld half-plane?  You can generate this solution quite easily using Fresnel integral code from, say, Numerical Recipes.  This was part of my standard repertoire when I wrote FDTD code.

Comment: @RonGordon I've briefly looked at the analytical solution, but, honestly, got a little lost. I'm gradually learning to read papers on this stuff, but it's a skill that's taking time to develop. I'll go-a-Googling. In your opinion, is Numerical Recipes the best place to start researching that? (Honestly, that seems like a better way to go, rather than relying on the correctness of another software package.)

Comment: NR is the best place to learn about issues you come across in basic scientific computing, not really to learn about things like the Sommerfeld solution.  If I were you, I would invest the time to understand this solution if at all within your power.  In any case, you may profit form the scicomp.SE community: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RonGordon Awesome - thanks for the advice. I'm a software guy from way back that decided to go down the EE path in school, which worked very well until I hit a road block with my master's thesis. Source code is easier for me to read and absorb than formal math. I'll post future questions on scicomp.